# Laravel 8 Fortify login says 429 TOO MANY REQUESTS

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, fortify

I'm having a problem related to 429 TOO MANY REQUESTS. I have used Laravel fortify and my web route is like

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/dashboard','DashboardController@dashboardView')
    ->name('dashboard')->middleware('auth');
```

The problem is coming intermittently, after successful login I redirected to dashboard if immediately I hit logout and instantly try to log-in it is giving 429 TOO MANY REQUESTS and in the address bar the URL is http://127.0.0.1:8000/login. Now if I wait there for a sec and refresh the page it redirects to the dashboard page.

I have searched the web, everyone is saying about throttle and I'm not seeing this as the solution. Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same problem today and did some debugging. When registering the /login route, Fortify applies the `Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests:login` middleware to it. This means, for every request to that route, the `ThrottleRequests` middleware will call the `RateLimiter` instance for that specified key. Apparently, Fortify doesn't register a `RateLimiter` for the `login` key.

Due to the missing key in the `$limiters` property of the `RateLimiter` instance, the `ThrottleRequests` middleware uses its default fallback, which doesn't handle the edge case "there SHOULD be a rate limiter for that key, but there isn't." really well. The `$maxAttempts` variable is set to 0 and will result in flaky rate limiting behaviour.

I feel like this is a bug in Fortify, because rate limiting is also happening in the `\Laravel\Fortify\Actions\EnsureLoginIsNotThrottled` action, which is invoked in the `\Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\AuthenticatedSessionController` controller. I didn't check this on a fresh Laravel installation, though, so I don't want to jump to conclusions here.

Anyway, long story short: As a workaround, you can simply register a rate limiter for the "login" key in some of your providers, e. g. `AppServiceProvider` or `AuthServiceProvider`:

```php
public function boot()
{
    RateLimiter::for("login", function () {
        Limit::perMinute(5);
    });
}
```

**Edit:**
I just realized that the rate limiter for the "login" key is indeed provided by Fortify within the `FortifyServiceProvider` class. If you happen to have a problem similar to the one discussed above, make sure that you added the `FortifyServiceProvider` class to your `providers` array in the `config/app.php`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply, I have solved the problem by doing this in the class FortifyServiceProvider. In the boot method before calling the login view. Fortify::loginView(function () {
            Artisan::call('cache:clear');
            return view('forepart.login.user_login');
        });

Comment: While this will work, busting your cache on every user login is probably not the best way to go about it.

Comment: @ChrisMeh you awesome bro! Thanks a bunch ! My users actually reported getting 429 error in production, after entering the login information wrong just once! I was like what the heck it should at least give you 5 chances. Just to add a small note, the login key defined in `FortifyServiceProvider` uses `email` by default, and if you're like me and don't use `email` field, you should change that.

Answer (score 3):

I tried everything including the Best Answer but it just didn't work.

Therefore, not even changing the `RateLimiter` in the `FortifyServiceProvider` class.

I'd try to log in and get a 429 error **after just one login attempt**.

Here what was the issue for me, it was the the `config/fortify.php` file.

I had to change:

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Rate Limiting
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, Fortify will throttle logins to five requests per minute for
    | every email and IP address combination. However, if you would like to
    | specify a custom rate limiter to call then you may specify it here.
    |
    */

    'limiters' => [
        'login' => 'login',
        'two-factor' => 'two-factor',
    ],
```

to

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Rate Limiting
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, Fortify will throttle logins to five requests per minute for
    | every email and IP address combination. However, if you would like to
    | specify a custom rate limiter to call then you may specify it here.
    |
    */

    'limiters' => [
        'login' => 5,
        'two-factor' => 5,
    ],
```

And funny enough the problem is inherent in the Fortify package itself when you run:

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Fortify\FortifyServiceProvider"` as per their [documentation instructions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#installation).

This fundamental reason being that code within `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php` is not able to correctly parse the limit:

```
    /**
     * Resolve the number of attempts if the user is authenticated or not.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int|string  $maxAttempts
     * @return int
     */
    protected function resolveMaxAttempts($request, $maxAttempts)
    {
        if (Str::contains($maxAttempts, '|')) {
            $maxAttempts = explode('|', $maxAttempts, 2)[$request->user() ? 1 : 0];
        }

        if (! is_numeric($maxAttempts) && $request->user()) {
            $maxAttempts = $request->user()->{$maxAttempts};
        }

        return (int) $maxAttempts;
    }
```

, which means, `'login'` is just parsed as `0` and that's what it returns.

Now I don't have to run `php artisan cache:clear` just to test.

Answer (score 0):

go to

```
app/http/kernel.php
```

and remove from `routeMiddleware` list the line

```
'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
php artisan cache:clear
```