# 429 Too Many Requests Laravel 8 (only with one account)

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I was developing my app since three months ago, but today when I was login with my test user (everyday a used this credentials for tests).

```
User: mail@mail.com
password: 123456
```

I received the error

> **429 Too Many Requests Laravel 8**

And this only happens for this account, so I think this isn't related with Rate Limiting on Laravel 8

I used seed and factory for seeding my database, and I have 100 users, when I login with another test account, there is no problems, for example:

```
User: dannie27@example.com
password: 123456
```

I have no problems working whith another account, but this look like very curious to me, so, someone knows what's going on here?

Pd: I already restarted the database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 8 Fortify login says 429 TOO MANY REQUESTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66014899/laravel-8-fortify-login-says-429-too-many-requests)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this URL to solve your issue:

[Laravel 8 Fortify login says 429 TOO MANY REQUESTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66014899/laravel-8-fortify-login-says-429-too-many-requests)

Answer (score 0):

I was working on another project, and I had the same error, but this time I could fix with:

```
php artisan config:cache
```