# Laravel how to increase email/verify rate limit throttle

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 10 and Laravel Fortify to handle email verification. When a user signs up to my platform, an email is sent to them (the default laravel email) which contains a link that takes them to a URL like:

> http://localhost:8005/email/verify/23/8f4b1a4a0ea66cfb264bc747d247f9529d7ec3b6?expires=1703525853&signature=81bda2c7c9bf2c8bc9a07ca31c2a1d78620bda407baf1a7d432f169a801d2158

The problem is that I keep seeing the Laravel **429 TOO MANY REQUESTS** despite my application's rate limiter being set to 200/min

```php
/**
 * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
 */
protected function configureRateLimiting(): void
{
    RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(200)->by($request->user()?->id ?: $request->ip());
    });
}
```

What exactly am I missing here? I'd like to allow more requests per minute for email verification.

Comment: Have a look at this: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66014899/laravel-8-fortify-login-says-429-too-many-requests)

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be setting the following in the `limiters` array key in the Fortify config file:

```php
'verification' => '30,1'
```